# Zend Framework Custom Validation Class Error Message

Tags: php, zend-framework, forms

The validation fails as it should but does not return the error message.

```
       $form->addElement('text', 'phone_number', array(
     'required' => true,
       'validators' => array(
         array('NotEmpty', true, array('messages' => 'Enter a valid Phone Number')),
           array('regex', false, array('pattern' => '/\([0-9]{3}\)\s[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}/',
              'messages' => 'Enter a valid Phone Number'
     )),
           'CheckPhoneNumber'),

       ),
   ));
```

Custom Class:

```
class Custom_Validators_CheckPhoneNumber extends Zend_Validate_Abstract{
const IN_USE = 'inUse';

protected $_messageTemplates = array(
    self::IN_USE => "'%value%' is currently in use"
);

public function isValid($value)
{
    $this->_setValue($value);

        $user_check = Users::getActive(preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $value));
        if($user_check->id){
            $this->_error(self::IN_USE);
            return false;
        }

  return true;
}
```

}

Just fails does not give the "IN_USE" error.

Answer (score 2):

Is it only the phone_number element which doesn't display errors or are there others?

Have you turned off default decorators with `disableLoadDefaultDecorators`?

How about this supplying the custom validator in an array:

```
$form->addElement(
    'text', 'phone_number', array(
        'required' => true,
        'validators' => array(
            array(
                'NotEmpty', true, array(
                    'messages' => 'Enter a valid Phone Number'
                )
            ),
            array(
                'regex', false, array(
                    'pattern' => '/\([0-9]{3}\)\s[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}/',
                    'messages' => 'Enter a valid Phone Number'
                )
            ),
            array(
                'CheckPhoneNumber'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that it fails in your custom validator?
Try to make sure that it actually fails in the custom validator.

If not, check if you have correct prefix path configured for elements of the form

```
$form->addElementPrefixPath(
  'Custom_Validators',
  'Custom/Validators',
  'validate'
);
```

The code for custom validator seems to be fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
   $form->addElement('text', 'phone_number', array(
 'required' => true,
   'validators' => array(
     array('NotEmpty', true, array('messages' => 'Enter a valid Phone Number')),
       array('regex', false, array('pattern' => '/\([0-9]{3}\)\s[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}/',
          'messages'=>array(Zend_Validate_Regex::NOT_MATCH=>'%value% is not a valid phone')
 )),
       'CheckPhoneNumber'),

   ),
));
```