# How to set custom error message zend form element file?

Tags: php, file, zend-framework, element, validation

So I am using Zend and I have a Zend form with a Zend_Form_Element_File and three validators:
1. setRequired
2. Extension
3. Size

```
 $this->browse = new Zend_Form_Element_File('Browse');
 $this->browse->setRequired(false)->removeDecorator('errors')->removeDecorator('label')
->addValidator('Extension', true, 'pdf')->addValidator('Size', false, 2000000);
```

I want to set custom error messages for these validators but do not know how.

The reason I want to set a custom error message is because I have a custom decorator with which I grab all errors when the form is not valid with isValid() and display them at the top of the form. The method for which I am grabbing errors in the form is getErrors().

I've also tried: http://www.mail-archive.com/fw-general@lists.zend.com/msg25779.html
by doing:

```
 $validator = new Zend_Validate_File_Upload();
 $validator->setMessages(array('fileUploadErrorNoFile' => 'Upload an image!''));
```

and doing

```
 $this->browse->addValidator($validator);
```

Any help?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

this is how i use to set custom validator message.

```
$file = new Zend_Form_Element_File('file');
$file->setLabel('File Label')
     ->setMaxFileSize('512000')
     ->addValidator('Count', true, 1)
     ->addValidator('Size', true, 512000)
     ->addValidator('Extension', true, 'jpg,jpeg,png,gif');

$file->getValidator('Count')->setMessage('You can upload only one file');
$file->getValidator('Size')->setMessage('Your file size cannot upload file size limit of 512 kb');
$file->getValidator('Extension')->setMessage('Invalid file extension, only valid image with file format jpg, jpeg, png and gif are allowed.');
```

here are some of the links that may prove useful to understand custom validator message.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.messages.html

[Zend Framework Custom Validation Class Error Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739508/zend-framework-custom-validation-class-error-message)

[Can't set custom validator messages in Zend_Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9517524/cant-set-custom-validator-messages-in-zend-form)

Comment: Thanks for this! Been hunting for a way to do this but it wasn't overly clear in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->browse = new Zend_Form_Element_File('Browse');
$this->browse->setRequired(true)
             ->removeDecorator('errors')
             ->removeDecorator('label')
             ->addValidator('Extension', true, 'pdf')
             ->addValidator('Size', false, 2000000)
             //->setMessage('You custom message')
             ->addValidator('File_Upload', true, array('messages'=>'You custom message'));
```

Answer (score 1):

To add custom message on zend_form_element_file, see following code,

```
   $browse = new Zend_Form_Element_File('Browse');
   $browse->addValidator('Extension', false, array('pdf',
               'messages'=>array('fileExtensionFalse'=>'file extension is not supported'))
          ->addValidator('Size', false, array(2000000,
                'messages'=>array('filesizefalse'=>'maximum 2000000 supported'));
```